# Known issues with Resharper 6

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, resharper-6.0

Im having real problems using Resharper-6 with VisualStudio-2008, specuially during debugging, as soon as click the "F5" to let it run, VS2008 crashes and restarts, is it a know issue, did anybody face such problems?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't encountered that issue personally. It is definitely the fault of ReSharper? Does the problem go away if you uninstall ReSharper?
As for known issues try the following:

- [ReSharper FAQ](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/resharper/kb?view=overview)
- [ReSharper Forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/resharper)
- [ReSharper Issue Tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/RSRP)

If it's definitely down to ReSharper then I'd recommend adding a support request to the Issue Tracker.